# Evitar que los registros de la tabla desaparezcan al recargar la pagina

Tags: javascript, mvc, razor

Tengo una `tabla` que muestra una `lista` de libros, en cada `fila` de esta `tabla` tengo un `botón` "agregar a carrito" que al hacer click se activa una función de `javascript` llamada "loadInTable" cuyo resultado es mostrar los libros seleccionados en otra tabla.
Los datos me los muestra perfectamente en la tabla con la función de `javascript`, pero al recargarse la pagina los datos que estaban en la tabla desaparecen, pero si hago click nuevamente en el `botón` "agregar a carrito" vuelven a aparecer esos datos(seguramente debe ser porque esos datos estan guardados en una `sessionStorage`). Lo que quiero es que esos datos que se habían agregado a la `tabla` no me desaparezcan al recargarse la pagina. Como podría solucionarlo?.

Aca el código `javascript`

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    //DECLARACION DE VARIABLES QUE SE VAN A USAR EN LAS FUNCIONES
    //traigo lo que esta guardao en las sessionStorage
    var json = sessionStorage.getItem("arrayId");
    var json2 = sessionStorage.getItem("arrayNames");

    //declaro los array
    var arrId = [];
    var arrNames = [];
    //si las sessionStorage no estan vacias se agrega su contenido a los array
    if (json != null) {
        arrId = JSON.parse(json);
        show(arrId)
    }

    if (json2 != null) {
        arrNames = JSON.parse(json2);
        show(arrNames)
    }

    function loadInTable(idLibro, nombreLibro) {

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var body = sessionStorage.getItem('tabla');

            if (body != null && body != "null") {
                $("#tblLibros tbody").append(sessionStorage.getItem('tabla'));
            }
        });

        //guardo los idLibro y nombres de libro en los array
        arrId.push(idLibro);
        arrNames.push(nombreLibro);
        //guardo los array en sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.setItem("arrayId", JSON.stringify(arrId));
        sessionStorage.setItem("arrayNames", JSON.stringify(arrNames));

        var tbody = document.querySelector('#tblLibros tbody');//aca le digo que los datos me los va a mostrar dentro de la etiqueta tbody de la tabla #tblLibros
        tbody.innerHTML = '';//limpio siempre el tbody para que cuando vuelva a hacer click en el boton llenar tabla, no me duplique los elementos
        //traigo el array guardado en el sessionStorage
        var names = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("arrayNames"));//traigo los nombre del libro
        var cantNames = names.length;//calculo cuantos elementos tiene

        for (var i = 0; i < cantNames; i++) {
            //creo una fila para cada nombre de libro
            var fila = document.createElement('tr');//aca creo la fila
            var celdaNames = document.createElement('td');//creo la celda para nombres
            //aca imprimo cada elemento de arrNames
            var nodoTextoNames = document.createTextNode(names[i]);
            celdaNames.appendChild(nodoTextoNames);//le asigno a c/u de las celdas, el nombre del libro
            fila.appendChild(celdaNames);//le asigno a c/u de las filas, la celda
            tbody.appendChild(fila);//le asigno las filas al tbody de la tabla      
        }
        //guarda la tabla en un una sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.setItem('tabla', $("#tblLibros tbody").html())
    }

    function show(array) {

        var pval = "";

        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            pval = pval + array[i] + "<br/>";
        }

        //muestro el array
        document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = pval;
    }

   
</script>
```

Aca el código `.cshtml` donde esta tabla con el `boton` agregar a carrito.

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-primary mt-5 table-bordered" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Autor</th>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Imagen</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @if (Model.Count() == 0)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6" style="color:red">
                        No Match any document
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

            else
            {
                foreach (Libro item in Model)
                {
                    autor = sa.getAutor(item.IdAutor);
                    editorial = es.GetEditorial(item.IdEditorial);
                    category = cs.getCategoria(item.IdCategoria);
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <input type="hidden" name="inputText" id="inputText" value="@item.IdLibro" />
                            @Html.ActionLink("Mostrar", "MostrarLibro", "Usser", new { idLibro = item.IdLibro }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
                            <button onclick="loadInTable('@item.IdLibro', '@item.Nombre');" class="btn btn-info">Agregar a carrito</button>
                        </th>
                        <th>@item.IdLibro</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2">@item.Nombre</th>
                        <th>@autor.Nombre</th>
                        <th>@category.Nombre</th>
                        <th class="col-md-3"><textarea rows="4" cols="40" readonly>@item.Descripcion</textarea></th>
                        <th>@item.Precio</th>
                        <th><img src="/@item.UrlImagen.Replace("\\", "/")" width="80" height="100" /></th>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

y por ultimo la `tabla` donde aparecen los libros seleccionados por el usuario

```html
<div id="table-wrapper">
    <div id="table-scroll">
        <table class="table table-striped table-primary mt-5 table-bordered" id="tblLibros">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Libros seleccionados</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LO SOLUCIONE DE ESTA FORMA:**

1) Hice una función en `javascript` para que traiga el `tbody`guardado en la `sessionStorage` y lo muestre en la `tabla`.

```js
 function showTbodyTable() {

        $("#tblLibros tbody").append(sessionStorage.getItem('tabla'));
    }
```

2)Coloque abajo de todo este `script` para que cada vez que se recargue la pagina, se active la función que muestra el `tbody` en la `tabla`.

```js
<script>
    //Cada vez que se recargue la pagina va a cargar el tbody de la tabla
    window.addEventListener("load", showTbodyTable, false);
</script>
```

Aca muestro el código completo en `javascript`

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
 //DECLARACION DE VARIABLES QUE SE VAN A USAR EN LAS FUNCIONES
    //traigo lo que esta guardao en las sessionStorage
    var json = sessionStorage.getItem("arrayId");
    var json2 = sessionStorage.getItem("arrayNames");

    //declaro los array
    var arrId = [];
    var arrNames = [];
    //si las sessionStorage no estan vacias se agrega su contenido a los array
    if (json != null) {
        arrId = JSON.parse(json);
        //show(arrId)
    }

    if (json2 != null) {
        arrNames = JSON.parse(json2);
        show(arrNames)
    }

 //Obtengo el tbody guardado en la sessionStorage
    var body = sessionStorage.getItem('tabla');

    if (body != null) {
        $("#tblLibros tbody").append(sessionStorage.getItem('tabla'));
    }

    
    function loadInTable(idLibro, nombreLibro) {

        //guardo los idLibro y nombres de libro en los array
        arrId.push(idLibro);
        arrNames.push(nombreLibro);
        //guardo los array en sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.setItem("arrayId", JSON.stringify(arrId));
        sessionStorage.setItem("arrayNames", JSON.stringify(arrNames));
        
        var tbody = document.querySelector('#tblLibros tbody');//aca le digo que los datos me los va a mostrar dentro de la etiqueta tbody de la tabla #tblLibros
        tbody.innerHTML = '';//limpio siempre el tbody para que cuando vuelva a hacer click en el boton llenar tabla, no me duplique los elementos
        //traigo el array guardado en el sessionStorage
        var names = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("arrayNames"));//traigo los nombre del libro
        var cantNames = names.length;//calculo cuantos elementos tiene

        for (var i = 0; i < cantNames; i++) {
            //creo una fila para cada nombre de libro
            var fila = document.createElement('tr');//aca creo la fila
            var celdaNames = document.createElement('td');//creo la celda para nombres
            //aca imprimo cada elemento de arrNames
            var nodoTextoNames = document.createTextNode(names[i]);
            celdaNames.appendChild(nodoTextoNames);//le asigno a c/u de las celdas, el nombre del libro
            fila.appendChild(celdaNames);//le asigno a c/u de las filas, la celda
            tbody.appendChild(fila);//le asigno las filas al tbody de la tabla
        }

        //guarda la tabla en un una sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.setItem('tabla', $("#tblLibros tbody").html())
    }

    function showTbodyTable() {

        $("#tblLibros tbody").append(sessionStorage.getItem('tabla'));
    }

   
    function show(array) {

        var pval = "";

        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            pval = pval + array[i] + "<br/>";
        }

        //(Para comprobar)muestro el contenido del array en la etiqueta <p id="pText"></p>
        document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = pval;
    }

    function comprar() {

        var uri = '@Url.Action("Comprar", "Usser")';
        //compruebo array vacio
        if (arrId.length === 0)
        {
            alert("El carro esta vacío!, agregue un libro.")
        }
        else
        {
             //aca paso el array 'myArr' al controlador de mvc usando json
            $.ajax({
                url: uri,
                data: JSON.stringify(arrId),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json'
            });
        }
    }

</script>

<script>
    //Cada vez que se recargue la pagina va a cargar el tbody de la tabla
    window.addEventListener("load", showTbodyTable, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hola puedes usar localStorage

Para guardar información usa

```
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')
```

y para obtenerla

```
localStorage.getItem('key')
```

En tu caso podrías guardar tu tabla y al momento de cargar la pagina solo le haces append

```
localStorage.setItem('tabla', $("#idTabla tbody").html())
```

y cuando cargas

```
$("#idTabla tbody").append(localStorage.getItem('tabla'))
```

**Actualización**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //DECLARACION DE VARIABLES QUE SE VAN A USAR EN LAS FUNCIONES
    //traigo lo que esta guardao en las localStorage
    var json = localStorage.getItem("arrayId");
    var json2 = localStorage.getItem("arrayNames");

    //declaro los array
    var arrId = [];
    var arrNames = [];
    //si las localStorage no estan vacias se agrega su contenido a los array
    if (json != null) {
        arrId = JSON.parse(json);
        show(arrId)
    }

    if (json2 != null) {
        arrNames = JSON.parse(json2);
        show(arrNames)
    }

    function loadInTable(idLibro, nombreLibro) {

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var body = localStorage.getItem('tabla');

            if (body != null && body != "null") {
                $("#tblLibros tbody").append(localStorage.getItem('tabla'));
            }
        });

        //guardo los idLibro y nombres de libro en los array
        arrId.push(idLibro);
        arrNames.push(nombreLibro);
        //guardo los array en localStorage
        localStorage.setItem("arrayId", JSON.stringify(arrId));
        localStorage.setItem("arrayNames", JSON.stringify(arrNames));

        var tbody = document.querySelector('#tblLibros tbody');//aca le digo que los datos me los va a mostrar dentro de la etiqueta tbody de la tabla #tblLibros
        tbody.innerHTML = '';//limpio siempre el tbody para que cuando vuelva a hacer click en el boton llenar tabla, no me duplique los elementos
        //traigo el array guardado en el localStorage
        var names = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("arrayNames"));//traigo los nombre del libro
        var cantNames = names.length;//calculo cuantos elementos tiene

        for (var i = 0; i < cantNames; i++) {
            $("#tblLibros tbody").append(`<tr><td>${names[i]}</td></tr>`);     
        }

        //guarda la tabla en un una localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('tabla', $("#tblLibros tbody").html())
    }

    function show(array) {

        var pval = "";

        for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            pval = pval + array[i] + "<br/>";
        }

        //muestro el array
        document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = pval;
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Gracias @Jorge Luis por responder! lo de guardar la tabla es buena idea, me podrias mostrar como hacerlo en mi código? ya que intente hacerlo recién pero no me funciona, evidentemente algo estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: @Claudio Hola una pregunta cada vez que ejecutas loadInTable(idLibro, nombreLibro) le agrega una fila a la tabla verdad?

Comment: si claro, se agrega una fila a la tabla!. Hice lo que me mostraste, pero sigue sin funcionar, al recargarse la pagina los libros de la tabla seleccionados desaparecen.  lo que me dijiste que ponga al inicio del javascript no me funciona, ,pero si lo pongo al inicio de la funcion LoadInTable me carga los datos, pero al recargarse la pagina vuelven a desaparecer. Por ahí si agregas tu  código al mi codigo js que publique funcione, porque no se que error pueda tener.

Comment: Tienes Jquery?  O que error te marca

Comment: Ya en lugar de and es && en el que no te funciona

Comment: No me marca ningún error!, con respecto a Jquery, estoy usando MVC asi que debería tener jquery, es mas, el símbolo $ me reconoce que es const $: JqueryStatic.

Comment: el && ya lo había corregido.

Comment: Te puse un ejemplo, espero te sirva, no se ejecuta aqui pero puedes copiarlo y pegarlo en un archivo .html y abrirlo en el navegador

Comment: Acabo de Editar mi código javascript en la publicación, agregando las lineas de código que hiciste, para ver si puse algo mal.

Comment: @Claudio Hola prueba como te lo puse

Comment: gracias! copié tu código, los libros seleccionados se me agregan a la tabla, pero al recargar la pagina desaparecen de la tabla.

Comment: @Claudio, es porque tenia sessionStorage en lugar de local ya actualice

Comment: Gracias Jorge!, pero sigue sin funcionar, al recargarse la pagina desaparecen los libros de la tabla.

Comment: Mmm esta raro prueba cambiando todos los sessionStorage por loadStariga

Comment: loadStariga?? es la primera vez que leo eso, de todas forma reemplace las session por loadStariga y haciendo esto ni siquiera me pone los elementos seleccionados en la tabla.

Comment: no perdón error de dedo loadStorage como en en código que te actualice arriba

Comment: Gracias Jorge lo acabo de copiar y pegar pero tampoco me sirvió!, como siempre los datos se borran de la tabla. Igualmente por que usar localStorage ? eso genera que si cierro el navegador y lo vuelvo a abrir, esos datos siguen guardados por tiempo indefinido, y no me parece conveniente eso, al menos para este caso, por esa razón use las sessionStorage. Pero aún usando indistintamente session o local no funciona.